# Definition of Ordered and Unordered Estimator?

Tags: estimators

I am searching the definition of ordered and unordered estimator. Would you please help me with these two definitions ?

Answer (score 1):

Ordered estimator: The estimator which are based on the ordered of units selected in the sample and do not require inclusion of probabilities is called ordered estimator.
Unordered estimator : The estimator which does not depend on the order in which the units are drawn within the sample is known as Unordered estimator.